# How can i make php echo display in an ordered, nice way?

Tags: php, html, css

i need some help.

I am making a page to display some events.

I have the following code:

Skole.php:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<head>

<style>
    #container {
        height: 100%;
    }

</style>
<?php

// LOKAL VERSJON

include 'php/local-query.php';

// LIVE VERSJON
/*
include 'php/live-query.php';
*/
?>
<body ontouchstart>
<?php 
include_once 'php/header.php';

$skoleListe = Skole::all();
$eventListe = Event::all();
$skoleAttributter = '';
$eventAttributter = '';
$skoleIsSet = '';

$distinctEvent = Event::distinct()->get(['type']);

if(isset($_GET['skoleId'])) {
    $skoleIsSet = $_GET['skoleId'];
}


foreach($skoleListe as $skole) {
    $skoleAttributter.= '<option value="skole.php?skoleId=' . $skole['id'] . 
'">' . $skole['navn'] . '</option>';
}

foreach($distinctEvent as $event) {
    $eventAttributter.= '<option value="skole.php?skoleId=' . $skoleIsSet . 
"&event=" . $event['type'] . '">' . $event['type'] . '</option>';
}
?>

<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location= this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="">Velg arrangementstype</option>
<?= $eventAttributter; ?>
```

I dont know why this space showed up, but the following is also a part of Skole.php

```
<div id="container">

<?php include 'php/EventCard.php'; ?>


</div>

<?php

include_once 'php/footer.php';?>

</body>
```

Then i have my eventcard.php:

```
<!doctype HTML>

<head>

    <style>
        #events{
            display: inline-block;
            line-height: 1px;
            opacity: 0;
            padding: 100px;
            animation-name: eventsAnim;
            animation-duration: 4s;
            animation-fill-mode: forwards;
        }

        @keyframes eventsAnim{
            from {opacity: 0;}
            to {opacity: 1;}
        }

    </style>


</head>

<body>

<?php

error_reporting( error_reporting() & ~E_NOTICE );

$events = Event::with('skoler')->get();
$skoleIsSet = $_GET['skoleId'];
$eventIsSet = $_GET['event'];


if($skoleIsSet && !$eventIsSet) {
    foreach($events as $event) {
        if($event['skole_id'] == $skoleIsSet) {

            echo '<div id="events"><h1>' . $event['title'] . '</h1>';
             echo '<p>Beskrivelse: ' . $event['description'] . '</p>';
            echo '<p>Pris: ' . $event['pris'] . '</p>';
            echo '<p>Dato: ' . $event['date'] . '</p></div>';

        }
    }
} else {
    foreach($events as $event) {
        if($event['type'] == $eventIsSet && $event['skole_id'] == $skoleIsSet) {
            echo '<div id="events"><h1>' . $event['title'] . '</h1>';
            echo '<p>Beskrivelse: ' . $event['description'] . '</p>';
            echo '<p>Pris: ' . $event['pris'] . '</p>';
            echo '<p>Dato: ' . $event['date'] . '</p></div>';
        }
    }
}
?>

</body>
```

This is a picture of the result in skole.php:

[image]

As you can see, they are "out of order".

How can i make the entries appear in a more ordered way, "In line"?
So that no matter how many letters the entries contain they will still appear at the same location with the same spaces between eachother?

I hope that was clear enough.

Thanks!

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Show us these 3 methods as they seem to be getting your data `$skoleListe = Skole::all();` and `$eventListe = Event::all();` and `Event::distinct()`

Comment: Use a grid. Google Bootstrap, Skeleton, PureCSS, Foundation, etc, etc.

Comment: Im sorry, it was quite messy but i will try to make it better.

Comment: If you want to make every event card to use same width, try changeing width to some percentage. For exampe, 4 eventcards per line will have 25 percent width each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use div containers with float: left

```css
div{
    width: 25%;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    text <br>
    sample text
</div><div>
    text <br>
    sample text
</div><div>
    text <br>
    sample text
</div><div>
    text <br>
    sample text
</div><div>
    text <br>
    sample text
</div><div>
    text <br>
    sample text
</div><div>
    text <br>
    sample text
</div>
```

Use div elements with 25% width to make them appear 4 in a row

Answer (score 0):

You can sort using this method:

```
$skoleListe = Skole::all().sort();
```